# How to fix the space come by Datetime in JSON response

Tags: php, json

I want to remove the space which I get from the datetime. Because of this JSON found in invalid format.
Below is my JSON response:

```
{
"txId": "226334",
"createdAt":"2019-06-20
18: 33: 51","details":"Transfered
out","account_name_2":"","currency":"myr","amount":"-44.00","balance":"44,
272.80"}
```

below is my code

```
$data['transactions'] = [];
        foreach ($transactions as $tx) {
            $data['transactions'][] = array(
                'txId' => $tx['id'],
                'createdAt' => trim($tx['created_at']),
                'details' => str_replace(" "," ",$this->lang->line($tx['description'])),
                'account_name_2' => isset($merchants[$tx['account_name_2']]) ? $merchants[$tx['account_name_2']] : $tx['account_name_2'],
                'currency' => $currency,
                'amount' => $tx['amount'] > 0 ? '+' . number_format($tx['amount'] * $forex['buy_in'], 2) : number_format($tx['amount'] * $forex['buy_in'], 2),
                'balance' => number_format($total * $forex['buy_in'], 2)
            );
            $total -= number_format($tx['amount'] * $forex['buy_in'], 2);
        }

        $this->respSuccess($data);
```

Comment: Its probably better to fix the format on the input (the one that makes the JSON)?

Comment: How did you generate/get the JSON?

Comment: I generate the JSON using this
json_encode(array("status"=>"1","data"=>$obj), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)

Comment: You really have `2019-06-20(line-break-here)18: 33: 51` stored as a created_at date in your database? Including the line break, and the spaces after the `:`? Then it is probably more that kind of bogus input data, that should get fixed.

Comment: It is just space between "2019-06-20" "18:33:51" no space after colon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `str_replace`

```
str_replace("\n","",$json);
```

You can replace by space if you need `str_replace("\n"," ",$json);`

[Check Here](https://3v4l.org/iIaIc)